# How to set dynamic text next to textfield extjs

Tags: extjs

I need to set a dynamic text (units of measurement,Eg:*C,mm) beside a textfield

I declared the text field as,

```
{
    xtype:'textfield',
    hidden:true,
    id:'XX',
    fieldLabel:'&nbsp;&nbsp;Value',
    name:'Value'                                
}
```

and label as

```
{
    xtype:'label',
    id:'X',
    name:'X'        
}
```

I could set and get the values but the alignment is the problem. Plz help me with that.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to wrap this textfield into fieldcontainer, something like:

```
{
    xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
    layout: 'hbox',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Temperature',
    }, {
        xtype: 'displayfield',
        value: '*C'
    }]
}
```